# Rails:Set the pagination on the right-bottom

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

I try to put pagination on the bottom right, but somehow it does not work.

I have already let pagination work on my page, and I have tried to set the position of this pagination, but it seems not work.

The code on the projects/index.html.erb:

```
<div class="pagination">
  <div class ="page_info">
    <%=paginate @projects%>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code on the projects.scss:

```css
.pagination{
  .pagination .page_info{
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

I want to put the pagination on the bottom right, but now it has not shown the correct position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap in your application,
the just add `float-right` class.

```
<div class="pagination">
  <div class ="page_info float-right">
    <%=paginate @projects%>
  </div>
</div>
```

make sure your outer div occupying complete width of the page.

Comment: thx for help. I have tried your answer and it does not work. But It will be work if  I do this way      
 <div class="float-right">                                                                                
        <%=paginate @projects%>
</div>

Comment: Glad it help you out. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Your pagination is not a text, but blocks with text, so try aligning them like blocks. Also in scss you dot not have to repeat names of parent classes:

```css
.pagination {
  .page_info {
    float: right;
  }
  clear: both;
}
```